# Exit position Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

How can I exit or close a position on a specific time of exchange in Pine Script.
Example
I have long position and want to close it on or before 1500 hrs as per Indian Time Zone.
Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time()` function for that.

Here is an example where it marks candles between 1200 and 1500. It shouldn't be difficult to adapt according to your needs.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

timeAllowed = input.session("1200-1500", "Allowed hours")

// Check to see if we are in allowed hours using session info on all 7 days of the week.
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")

plotchar(timeIsAllowed, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: But I am asking about if I have an open position, how can I close or exit it on 1500 hour in pine script?

Comment: Use `strategy.position_size` to figure out if you have an open position. Then `hour == 15` would tell you if it is 1500.